# Result from function call is not an array of floats

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Following my previous two posts ([post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908646/pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918600/dropping-nans-from-selected-data-in-pandas)), I have now reached the point where I use `scipy` to find a curve fit. However, the code I have produces an error.

A sample of the `.csv` file I'm working with is located in post1. I tried to copy and substitute examples from the Internet, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I have (the `.py` file)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

df = pd.read_csv("~/Truncated raw data hcl.csv", usecols=['time' , '1mnaoh trial 1']).dropna()
data1 = df

array1 = np.asarray(data1)
x , y = np.split(array1,[-1],axis=1)

def func(x, a , b , c , d , e):
    return a + (b - a)/((1 + c*np.exp(-d*x))**(1/e))

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, x , y , p0=[23.2, 30.1 , 1 , 1 , 1])

popt
```

From the limited research I've done, it might be a problem with the x and y arrays. The title states the error that is written. It is a `minpack.error`.

Edit: the error returned

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/test2.py", line 15, in <module>
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, x , y , p0=[23.2, 30.1 , 1 , 1 , 1])
  File "~/'virtualenvname'/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 744, in curve_fit
res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "~/'virtualenvname'/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 394, in leastsq
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace so we can see the error? Also, if you could post an example of your data that would help in diagnosing the error.

Comment: @caseWestern data in post 1, as written/linked

Comment: Would you please post a link to the .csv file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the split, the shape of x and y is (..., 1). This means that each element of them itself are arrays of length one. You want to flatten the array first, i.e. via `x = np.flatten(x)`.
But I think you don't need the split at all. You can just do the following

```
array1 = np.asarray(data1).T
x , y = array1
```

You want x and y to be the first and second columns of `array1`. So an easy way to achieve this is to transpose the array first. You could also access them via `[:,0]` and `[:,1]`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! If I may ask another brief question here, I get a "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  return a + (b - a)/((1 + c*np.exp(-d*x))**(1/e))" when I run it. What's wrong with my expression.

Comment: No problem. I think the warning happens during the fit. Since within the algorithm different values for the parameters are tested, there may be some cases which are mathematically not allowed. In your case this means that the expression within brackets might be negative (for c < 0). When performing the power function on this negative number, i.e. taking the root, this yields a warning since no complex numbers are taken into account.